# Org-mode in Spacemacs: with-eval-after-load and additional-packages

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

### Background

[Spacemacs documentation recommends](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#important-note) that you wrap additional org-mode configurations in `(with-eval-after-load 'org [...config...])`:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
   ;; here goes your Org config
   ))
```

This is because:

> Since version 0.104, spacemacs uses the org version from the org ELPA
>   repository instead of the one shipped with emacs. [...] Because of autoloading, calling to org functions will trigger the loading up of the org shipped with emacs which will induce conflicts.

But lets say you then want to use `some-package` that configures *org-mode* in various ways. The org-related function inside the `some-package.el` file are **not** wrapped in `with-eval-after-load`. This is true for most org-related packages, which just have a `require org` statement at the top.

**How then do you load `some-package` so that it does not conflict with spacemacs's org implementation?** My first though was to do this **[A]**:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
   (require 'some-package)
   ;;configure 'some-package and 'org-mode
   ))
```

Is this the correct approach? Also, if you follow this route for Melpa packages, Spacemacs will delete and reinstall the package every-time you evaluate your `dotfile`. To avoid this, the Melpa package has to first be added to **[B]**

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  (setq-default
    dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(some-package)
   ))
```

## Question

In general, will this code (**[A][B]**) ensure that my `some-package` (which provides customizations for org) does not mess with spacemacs' org implementation? Or do I actually have to edit the `some-package.el` file directly and wrap its org-related functions in `with-eval-after-load` (hope not)? Or some other way?

## update

I was told on gitter chat that its safe to do `dotspacemacs-additonal-packages` and `with-eval-after-load` as outlined above. So that's the solution.

## Note

For reference, That somepackage is [here](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-org.el) (it's not a Melpa package so **[B]** does not apply in this partuclar case), but my question is more of a general one.

Comment: For reference, this question was also raised [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8884).

Comment: ".... most org-related packages ... assume you're using the org version shipped with Emacs": AFAIK, they do *not* assume that: they assume that there is an org that they can use (which may or may not be true). If there is no org-mode loaded and you load such a package and it calls an autoloaded org function, it will try to load the default org shipped with emacs (which may cause a "mixed installation" if you then load ELPA-org somehow). But if you have ELPA-org already loaded and able to satisfy any requires, then there should be no problem: the emacs-supplied org will never be touched.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find out how to load the file from github, this is what I am doing now.

```
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (load-file "~/.emacs.d/private/scimax-org-babel-ipython.el"))
```

I have also tried the code below, but it downloads every time and delays the startup, there might have been some other problems

`(scimax-org-babel-ipython :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "jkitchin/scimax") :files ("scimax-org-babel-ipython.el"))`

The scimax library is pretty solid, I hope that the author will put it on melpa in the future.

A word of warning: **Changing any org settings before the correct org has been loaded will trigger a load of the wrong org version. This will completely mess up the installation. The only way to fix this was to remove all .elc files in the elpa folder**. I made the mistake when trying to load the files above, as they change org settings they will trigger a load. This problem manifests itself in strange warnings, like variable void or similar.